# How to remove nth element from command arguments in bash

Tags: bash, shift

How to I remove the nth element from an argument list in bash?

Shift only appears to remove the first n, but I want to keep some of the first. I want something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x

echo $@

shift (from position 2)

echo $@
```

So when I call it - it removes "house" from the list:

```
my.sh 1 house 3
1 house 3
1 3
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`set`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) builtin and [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
set -- "${@:1:1}" "${@:3}"
```

would remove the second positonal argument.

You could make it generic by using a variable:

```
n=2   # This variable denotes the nth argument to be removed
set -- "${@:1:n-1}" "${@:n+1}"
```

Comment: +1; `(( ... ))` is not strictly needed, it seems, as the indices are by default evaluated in an arithmetic context.

Comment: Not just seems :) From the man page: "length and offset are arithmetic expressions"

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, you're correct.  Got rid of those redundant `((...))`.

Comment: @devnull That's perfect as it leaves the changed arguments in $@ so rest of script can work without knowing elements were removed.

Comment: @jaypal Yes, within seconds of each other.

Answer (score 2):

```
a=$1
shift; shift

echo $a $@
```

If someone knows how to do this in a better way I am all ears!

Comment: The variables `a` and `b` are never used?

Comment: @FelixFrank I fixed what I think was a typo; the idea is to transfer the first  two arguments out of `$@` and into separate parameters.

Comment: Oh right - but `$b` should be omitted from the output, I guess.

Comment: Yea, my bad! Fixed it. Bugs everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use bash you can use a bash array

```
#!/bin/bash

arg=($0 $@)
```

or if you don't need argument $0

```
arg=($@)

# argument to remove
rm_arg=2
arg=(${arg[@]:0:$rm_arg} ${arg[@]:$(($rm_arg + 1))})

echo ${arg[@]}
```

Now instead of referencing `$1` you might use `${arg[1]}` .

Remember that bash arguments has an argument `$0` and bash arrays have an element `[0]`. So, if you don't assign bash argument $0 to the first element of a bash array `[0]` , Then you will find bash argument `$1` in your bash array `[0]` .

Answer (score -1):

```
arg=($@)
for VAR in $@; do
    case $VAR in
    A)
        echo removing $VAR
        arg=($(echo $@| sed "s/$VAR//"))
        ;;
      *)
        echo ${arg[@]}
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Results:

```
./test.sh  1 2 3 A 4 5
1 2 3 A 4 5
1 2 3 A 4 5
1 2 3 A 4 5
removing A
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: a solution without the explanation does not contribute much to understanding and education for the reader. you might want to add a few more words.

Comment: the solution does not match the question. when a certain member has the value 'A' a string pattern operation is applied to the whole argument string for removing that pattern. thats not the n-th element!
i further feel it might fail when some of the other args contain the letter "A".